# Fastest way to retrieve and display a specific post from another Wordpress site?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, rss

I would like to display a specific post from one Wordpress site on another Wordpress site via jQuery / Ajax.

How it's set up is I have a custom RSS feed which I use to output the title & featured image of each post. I am pulling these into a page on a separate Wordpress site. What I want to have happen is that when the user clicks on one of the post title, the full post will open up in the same window (via javascript).

Would it be faster (load time) to fetch the full post content & additional custom field values for that post by loading all the posts into a separate file in my theme such as load_full_posts.php, and using jQuery `.load()`

eg: `$('#div_id_in_your_page').load('ajax_page.html #required_div');`

Or would it be better to fetch it as XML from a custom feed and then use Ajax to pull it like so (note the URL to the feed would contain a GET variable which I would use to query for that specific post only in the custom RSS feed):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/feed/mycustomfeed?postID=#",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // output html
      }

    });
   }
});
```

If there is a better method than either of these - or security concerns with either of these - please let me know as I am not aware.. This is my first time ever working with RSS feeds.

Comment: Why don't you just include the content as part of the RSS feed then display it when the title is clicked? Surely that would be simpler than making ajax requests for every article

Comment: So you think it would be faster to just load ALL the posts on initial page load, rather than loading only the posts that the user chooses to actually open? My concern with this is that I will have to load 64 posts with featured images onto one page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need speed and reliability, I don't think loading data from a 3rd party site is the best way. What you should probably do is poll the feed on your backend and cache its data locally so that your application can directly serve it (or load it from your own servers).

Comment: The sites are both on the same server. One is a private site for employees only, but it has most of the data already entered; they don't want to have to update both sites so this is why we are trying to pull data from the private site to display on their public website.